# Convert the TensorflowLite model to optimized C code for STM32

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, stm32

I export a tensorflow lite floating point model from google teachable machine
(It is a file with one tflite file and one with label.txt file)
https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/audio
It is an audio classifying project and I planned to use it on STM32F746G-DISCOVERY（DISCO-F746NG）
while following the instruction provided in here :https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/AI:How_to_use_Teachable_Machine_to_create_an_image_classification_application_on_STM32#Hardware

During the step : Porting to a target board
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k10NI.png)

In this part we will use the stm32ai command line tool to convert the TensorflowLite model to optimized C code for STM32.
Start by opening a shell in your workspace directory, then execute the following command:

PC $> cd

PC $> stm32ai generate -m model.tflite -v 2

I don't know what does it means by opening a shell, powershell ? cmd ? python ?
I tried but it cannot recognize stm32ai ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ChO7.png)

p.s.
then I go for this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crJcDqIUbP4&ab_channel=Digi-Key
to use STM32 X-CUBE-AI on stm32cubeMX
and it failed to analyze the network
INTERNAL ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tolist

I don't know if the error are related or not

so how can I use the stm32ai command line tool ?
Is the stm32ai should have been installed somewhere in powershell ?

Comment: This is a sprawling question covering many topics and technologies. Focus on one clear question. Also: It's extremely rude to expect someone who's helping you go watch a YouTube video!

Comment: If you know any other way on how to convert the TensorflowLite model to optimized C code for STM32, I am very happy to know

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.